# Не могу написать программу

Tags: c

Напишите программу, которая получит от пользователя строку, состоящую из букв «a» и «b», которые
имеет длину 10 символов (каждый символ должен быть прочитан отдельно). Программа должна обнаруживать и
сигнал, если на входе есть последовательность «abba».(При это м нельзя использовать массивы и сортировку)У меня был подобный вариант, но сказали что он не подходит:

```
  void abba();
  int main()
  {
abba();
return 0;
  }

  void abba()
  {
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, k, l;
printf("Enter 10 characters");
scanf_s("%c", &a);
scanf_s("%c", &b);
scanf_s("%c", &c);
scanf_s("%c", &d);
scanf_s("%c", &e);
scanf_s("%c", &f);
scanf_s("%c", &g);
scanf_s("%c", &h);
scanf_s("%c", &k);
scanf_s("%c", &l);

if (a == 'a' && b == 'b' && c == 'b' && d == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");
if (b == 'a' && c == 'b' && d == 'b' && e == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");
if (c == 'a' && d == 'b' && e == 'b' && f == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");
if (d == 'a' && e == 'b' && f == 'b' && g == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is foun d!");
if (e == 'a' && f == 'b' && g == 'b' && h == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");
if (f == 'a' && g == 'b' && h == 'b' && k == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");
if (g== 'a' && h == 'b' && k == 'b' && l == 'a')
    printf("'abba' is found!");

  }
```

Comment: Конечные автоматы вам в помощь.

Comment: Мы то можем написать.. но никакого желания нет. Вот если бы вы показали что у вас уже готово, задали бы вопросы по тем участкам кода которые у вас не работают или не получается правильно реализовать.... тогда конечно мы бы помогли

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков У меня есть вариант только как написать это через рекурсию и я там ввожу символы через getchar, как осуществить это, что бы каждый ивол считывался отдельно я не знаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользуясь идеей о КА, написалось такое:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int state = 0;
    char c;
    while((scanf("%c",&c) == 1) && (c == 'a' || c == 'b')) {
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                if (c == 'a') state = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (c == 'b') state = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (c == 'b') state = 3;
                else state = 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (c == 'b') state = 0;
                else {
                    puts("abba!!!");
                    return 0;
                    };
                break;
            }
        }
    puts(" No abba :(");
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое, но не могли бы вы объяснить как это работает, никогда не сталкивалась с КА

Comment: Эта программа находит abba только в начале, если я введу ее к примеру, в середине, то она не работает

Comment: https://ideone.com/XcPYKx - вот пример с abba в средине строки. На какой строке у вас не работает?

Comment: https://ideone.com/keYcFl вот, посмотрите, возможно я что то не так написала

Comment: Вы писали: "получит от пользователя строку, состоящую из букв «a» и «b»". У меня любая буква, не равная a или b, невозможна и заканчивает работу программы - в строке могут быть только «a» и «b», так ведь? А вы передаете строку с другими буквами. Переписать несложнео, конечно, но скажитек точно условие.